# How to connect to MySQL server installed on 1 windows machine(XP) from another windows machine(Win 7)?

Tags: mysql

**Scenario:** I have MySQL 5.1 installed on my Windows XP machine, and it has the database and tables laid out. Now, I want to connect to that MySQL remotely from my Windows 7 machine and enter data into it.

I have configured my MySQL on the XP machine to accept connections from a outside machine by making a new user, with password, and also specifying my Win 7 machine's IP address as shown here - [Please See](http://forums.techguy.org/software-development/623379-solved-how-enable-remote-access.html) .

My problem is that I do not understand how to connect to MySQL from Win 7 machine, my approach is that I reach the directory where I have MySQL installed on my Win 7 machine from cmd and use the command - 'mysql -u [userid] –h [IP Address] –p', this is as I use to connect to MySQL locally on Win 7 machine, barring the IP address part.

**Please help me..what am I doing wrong ?, o is it all wrong ??, do I need a MySQL client on Win 7 machine for this ??, also, If I try to connect to MySQL on WIn XP machine from a linux machine..does it make it easier and more direct ??**

I'll really appreciate the help..

Regards,

Chirayu

Comment: it could be the order, try: mysql –h [IP Address] -u [userid] –p

Comment: Make sure Windows XP firewall is not blocking port 3306 or whatever port you are using for your MySQL.

Comment: The order was not an issue as I tried that, please see my comment in the 1 answer below.which might make things clear..Also, I added the port exception for 3306 in Win XP machine, diabled the anti-virus, and still the errors are as said below.
thanks for replying and I'll really appreciate help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the right thing.  What is the response to the command

```
mysql -h host -u user -p
```

Does it prompt for a password?  Does it blather about no route available?

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying, I did as you stated, and get the error: **ERROR 2003 (HY000): can't connect to MySQL server on 65.51.78.245 (10060)** , n it does ask for password before I get the mentioned error.
I just now tried logging in from Linux(Ubuntu), and when I try the same command from linux terminal, I get the error- **ERROR 2003 (HY000): can't connect to MySQl server on 65.51.78.245 (110)** , and it does ask for password before I get this error, n so when I try 'telnet 65.51.78.245 3306' in terminal, I get the error - **telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out**.

Comment: Temporarily disable the firewall on the MySQL machine to see if that is the problem.  I suspect it is dropping the ball on establishing the TCP connection.

Comment: I get the same 'telnet: unable to connect..' error when I use the telnet command...I'm at such a roadblock...please help... :((

Comment: The `mysql` command gives a `telnet` error?  That's weird!  Or do you mean you tried `telnet` to connect?

Comment: I meant, mysql command is giving the same error as before..and I tried telnet to see if anything is working and got the same error as before - **telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out**.

Comment: The telnet port is different from the SQL port.  Turn off the server's firewall and any anti-virus software to see if it is a SQL configuration issue.  Once you get it to connect and do queries, then things can be turned on one-by-one and properly configured for SQL to continue working.

Comment: @wallyk, thanks for still replying...and I have turned off the firewall completely, and also turned off the anti-virus...the errors are still he same ... I have searched all over the internet, but I cannot find a solution...2 things - **1) can it be because of the router ?** , and **2) Should I try the same thing over a different computer, just to see if the problem is localized to Win Xp machine ?**

Comment: 1) The route *could* be causing problems.  But if you can reach the server through *any* means, that is not the problem.  Try `ping 65.51.78.245` (from a command line prompt) and see if that is able to receive the replies.  2) Testing with another computer is always a good idea to help split the problem in half.

Comment: @wallyk, the ping works, but the telnet does not ! I am beginning to believe that it is a firewall issue, w.r.t. the company's wireless router which is not allowing me to connect 'in' to 1 system from another on the same wireless....I think I need to get into 2 same wired connections, and try it out...if you have any suggestion, please do say..I will post the final outcome anyways.

Comment: Well finally..the problem was with the company router as it had its own pseudo IP address's on all machines connected via wireless...solution ??, well I logged in through the 'wired connection', which gave me a real IP address, and tried to do the same telnet thing and everything...and it worked ! Will be happy to help anybody who gets stuck in similar situation in future.